# how to configure elasticsearch cluster with 3 nodes and also I have two nodes of Kibana to set HA. what is the the proper setup?

Tags: elasticsearch, nodes, kibana, elk

I have 3 nodes of elasticsearch. and two nodes of kibana That I want to set HA(for elastticsearch cluster).what is the proper setup for production environment for both elasticsearch cluster and kibana nodes setup?

Answer (score 1):

you should definitely read through - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/setup.html. it might seem like a lot, but it's good to understand how to do this correctly from the start

Kibana is at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/setup.html